# Closing a car insurance claim the day after filing it, with zero dollars paid and no actions taken on the claim: will premium typically go up?

Tags: insurance

Consider cases where you file a claim, and close the claim the next day, and the insurance company paid you zero dollars and took no actions on the claim such as towing or inspecting the vehicle etc.

For example, you file a claim telling the agent "I heard something hit my car while I was driving and now my brakes don't work right." You decide the next day this is probably not going to be covered and you call to say never mind, and they close without payment.

I have found several sites that say that in a case like this, typically the premium would not go up. But the sites I find that address this question are typically financially interested in selling insurance or related services, so there can be some reason to not be sure they're correct or truthful. Meanwhile I have a couple of people whose identity I can't verify who claim to work in this area and who say that typically premiums *will* go up in cases like this. But from past experience it is too common for people to be "chicken littling" when they say things like this on the internet.

How can I determine the truth as to what's typical in cases like this?

Comment: 1) Why would you do this in the first place? 2) That's a matter of the individual company's policies and practices; there is no "generally."

Answer (score 2):

My family had a slightly different situation. One of our cars was hit in front of our house while we were not home. We suspected it was by somebody backing out of a driveway.

We contacted the insurance company to start a claim, because we didn't want to pay out of pocket if nobody ever was identified. A few hours later the neighbor came over and admitted that they did it. We stopped our claim and their insurance company took over. A few days later our claim with our insurance company was no longer visible on the website. We continued to get our claim-free discount. Though we have no idea if there was a behind the scenes change in our premium calculation.

Yes call them to ask what repercussions your abandoned claim had. Keep in mind that the pricing model is complex, and the higher premium may not be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Premiums are paid for the risk. If you have an accident then you proved you are a higher risk, even if you never ask the insurance to pay out. The only way to find out is call them.

The best case is an insurance telling you how much they paid out, and giving you the choice between paying and higher premiums.